# The String.substring() in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test2{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s1 = "Delivery";
    String s2 = s1.substring(8);
    System.out.println(s2);
  }
}
```

Why does this gives a blank space? Shouldn't the eighth position out of bound?

Also, why is s1.charAt(8) prompts outOfBound error? Do they use different method to handle the problem?

Comment: No, it’s OK to begin the substring at the end of the string, it just gives you the empty string, `""` (the string has length 0).

Comment: Check the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

Comment: The documentation says “Throws: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.” You can take that to mean strictly larger. `beginIndex` is allowed to be equal to length (in your example both are 8).

Answer (score 2):

`substring` method throws the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` only when the `beginIndex` is greater than the `length` of the string **as shown in the below code** (**taken from `String` class `substring` method**):

```
int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
if (subLen < 0) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
}
```

Also, the same has been explained in the Javadoc as well, you can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
> begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the
> end of this string. Examples:
>
> "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
>
> "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
>
> "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)

Answer (score 1):

`string.substring(int id)` returns a substring of the string which starts at index `id`. `id` is an index, but not the position!

Remember, indexes start counting from 0!
Please, check the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

The part of `subString` method looks like this:

```
int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
if (subLen < 0) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
}
```

Comment: Nah, it doesn’t return a character, in this example that would not be possible. It returns a string (an empty one in the example).

Answer (score 0):

This will throw **IndexOutOfBoundsException** - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of your String. In your case beginIndex is 8 and length of String is also 8. That's the reason you are not getting IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to run the code in an IDE and debug 
Step-Into the method substring and your query will be answered

Check the source code of the Substring method

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex) {
        if (beginIndex < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
        }
        int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
        if (subLen < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
        }
        return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
    }
```

Here :

1. the begin index is 8,
2. 8 is not less than 0
3. **subLen =0 and is not less than 0**

Try passing 9 to the substring and you get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
    at com.iqp.standalone.Sample.main(Sample.java:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

See Java documentation about Strings here: [Java Strings Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Your `s1` lenght is 7.

charAt method looks like this:

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

Of course it will give you error!